# Python: Checking if a variable is greater or smaller if/else statement

Tags: python, json

**Hi everyone!** I am using `Python 2.7` and `xlrd` to convert a `.xlsx` file into a `.json` file! What I want to accomplish too with this script, is to draw conclusions from the input. This will also make sure that less human errors are made. But, there is a problem with my code. The user has to enter a certain value in a cell, which represents pages from a book per hundered. Want I want to check: are there more or less pages than 100. The code which I am using

```
import sys
import xlrd

dir = '/path/to/JSON/to/write'
dirworksheet = '/path/to/excel/file'

file = sys.argv[1]
fileJSON = sys.argv[1]+'.json'

work_path = os.path.join(dirworksheet,file)
full_path = os.path.join(dir,fileJSON)
worksheet = xlrd.open_workbook(work_path)
sheet_generalinfo = worksheet.sheet_by_index(0)

data_generalinfo = []

for colnumber in range(1, sheet_generalinfo.ncols):
    key1 = OrderedDict()
    row_value = sheet_generalinfo.col_values(colnumber)
    key1['publish_id'] = 1
    key1['book_name'] = row_value[1]
    key1['pages_per_100'] = float(row_value[2])
    if row_value[2]>= 1:
        key1['greater_or_smaller']='greater'
    else:
        key1['greater_or_smaller']='smaller'

    key1['samples'] = data_samples

    data_generalinfo.append(key1)

json = json.dumps(data_generalinfo)

with open(full_path, 'w') as datafile: 
    datafile.write(json)

print(full_path)
```

The code works fine! But when I look at the JSON file, it always says true! I have entered `0.3` in the excel file and `1.4`, but always `greater` is returned. What am I doing wrong in this statement?

Comment: Print the value in your code to make sure that you test the correct one.

Comment: Why are you doing if row_value[2]>= 1 instead of if row_value[2]>= 100: ?

Comment: Because the value is per 100, so 100 pages => 1

Comment: @C.Dlp  `print(row_value[6])` return `0.2`

Comment: @AnnaJeanine you just gave an example of index 6 printing `0.2` but your code checks index 2?

Comment: Sorry! Wrong copy. In my code it is index 6 but I edited the example to make it more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

potentially row_value[2] is a string when it's being imported. If so, then     it will always be true, because it's comparing a string to a number:

```
>>> '0.1'>1
9: True
```

Try converting all to floating points:

```
key1['pages_per_100'] = float(row_value[2])
```

Now that you've made things float, it will work, but you need to change your if statement:

```
for colnumber in range(1, sheet_generalinfo.ncols):
    key1 = OrderedDict()
    row_value = sheet_generalinfo.col_values(colnumber)
    key1['publish_id'] = 1
    key1['book_name'] = row_value[1]
    key1['pages_per_100'] = float(row_value[2])
    if row_value[2]>= 1:
        key1['greater_or_smaller']='greater'
    else:
        key1['greater_or_smaller']='smaller'
```

You put the float value into key1, but then your if statement still looks at the row_value, which is still a string. Change the line:

```
if row_value[2]>= 1:
```

to instead:

```
if key1['pages_per_100']>= 1:
```

Comment: Thank you for noticing this! But this still doesn't fix my problem. I adjusted my code and still the greater is returned:  `"pages_per_100" : 0.2, "greater_or_smaller" : "greater"`

Comment: In your code:
        if row_value[2]>= 1:
needs to be changed to
key1['pages_per_100']>=1 
because that's the thing you converted to float

Comment: I don't understand your comment?

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem!

Comment: Yeh waiting for StackOverflow to allow me!